# document.querySelectorAll - How to avoid getting nested elements with the given parameter?

Tags: javascript

I'm fetching one web and I need to get list of all elements with the given class name. The problem is that my array also contains nested elements (fetched from the parent) which also have the same class name.

Example:

```
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
   <div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

In this case I'm gonna receive 5 elements instead of 4 - I want to avoid getting the nested one. Is there  any solution to achieve what I'm looking for ?

Comment: I don't see any nested div in the example code you provided. Please update!

Comment: @Alex — The OP said that some were nested, not that they would always be the first child when nested. And all else being equal, the top item in the example HTML is a first child so your approach would filter it out even though it isn't nested.

Comment: @Alex — The question is asking for elements that are members of `someClass` that are not descendants of other elements which are members of `someClass`. … and you can't use first child to determine if an element has any descendants anyway.

Comment: @Alex — "X that has a child of any kind" is completely different to "X that has a descendant that is also X" which is also different what was actually asked which is "X that doesn't have an ancestor that is also X"

Comment: ah okay I understand @Quentin thats true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find all the elements that are members of the class
2. Convert the result to an array to get access to the `filter` method
3. Filter out any which match the selector "Descended from that class"

```js
const allSomeClass = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
const filtered = Array.from(allSomeClass).filter(
  element => !element.matches(".someClass .someClass")
);
console.log(filtered)
```

```html
<div id=1 class="someClass"></div>
<div id=2 class="someClass">
  <div id=3 class="someClass"></div>
</div>
<div id=4 class="someClass"></div>
<div id=5 class="someClass"></div>
```

See the [documentation for `matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) if you need a polyfill to support very old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any nested divs in your example, but I think you meant this:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("body > .someClass");
console.log(divs);
```

```html
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass">
  <div class="someClass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

You can target direct children of the `body` tag(or whatever container you're using) by using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>`